# is any way for broadcaster add user to join in live streaming

Tags: agora.io

is possible, broadcaster add any user to live and then interacting with each other and also audience show both screen as well as audio and video and their activities is this possible?. I found documentation but not clearly satisfied. If anyone know then let me know what is the right way for do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Agora SDK does provide that feature. In order to do that, you need to switch the user's role from audience to broadcaster and send the video stream to the remote users in the channel.

Please take a look at this article for detailed information: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/co_host_overview?platform=All%20Platforms

And the GitHub demo code here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/AgoraLive